# Firebase - Rules of transaction

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I try to set rules on Firebase, if uid (abc_x) === $account (abc_y), it can read data and everyone can insert,update data. But when i use transaction, it's report "Error: permission_denied"

```
 "countchat":{
    "$account": {
      ".read": "$account === auth.uid",
      ".write": "auth != null", 
    }
  },
```

Comment: If @cartant's answer does not solve your problem, share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction):

> When using transactions with Security and Firebase Rules in place, be aware that a client needs `.read` access in addition to `.write` access in order to perform a transaction.